# In 3d preview action, while using Activity View Controller showing a warning whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

// The quick actions
var previewActions:[UIPreviewActionItem] {

```
        let item1 = UIPreviewAction(title: "Share", style: .default) { (action:UIPreviewAction, vc:UIViewController) -> Void in

            self.shareAction()
            print("Shared")
        }

        return [item1]

    }

func shareAction(){
    // text, image to share
    let textToShare = self.selectedLabel ?? ""
    let image = self.selectedImage
    let subtitleToShare = self.selectedSubtitleLabel ?? ""

    // set up activity view controller
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [textToShare,image,subtitleToShare], applicationActivities: nil)

    // present the view controller
  //  let vc:UIViewController = (self.view.window?.rootViewController)!
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }  ** AT this point its showing up the error "Warning: Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: 0x7fe9e962bc90> on <Project Name.[1]PreviewViewController: 0x7fe9e941e4a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"and not performing the action**
```

[Check the image for the clear picture []
  [1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmTFG.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKZEP.jpg

> What needs to be done? where am going wrong? can someone please help me?

Comment: find your top VC and present your UIActivityViewController

Comment: i did'nt get you

Comment: the message says, that your current self, at the point where u present, is not in the window top hierarchy, means something else is over the controller or navigation stack. Are u sure, that your controller is on top of the hierarchy?

Comment: i got to present the ActivityController on a custom view instead of self, how could i achieve that.